# Broadcom STA wireless driver not activating

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, internet, broadcom

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the STA broadcom drivers give me an error saying "Sorry, installation  of this driver failed" when I try to activate in additional drivers

I know that the STA driver is what I need I checked in the terminal that I have  BCM4312

but I dont have internet access to the computer im trying to do this on because the ethernet port doesnt work so I need help in finding a way to install the STA drivers so I can start using wireless

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi driver is not installed and eithernet port is also not working then you can choose or arrange any one to connect with internet for 1st time or initial setup drivers (wifi, graphic) :-

USB LAN card,

Mobile (smart phone) but you should specific here network and additional information,

Data Card/ Internet Toggle that work in linux

These option will essentially help you to setup the ubuntu and update drivers ,
and try to reinstall Broadcom driver because it support BCM4312 and  wifi will also work.

Comment: again, I have absolutely no internet access to this computer. Isnt there a way for me do download the driver on a usb stick and install it that way?

Comment: No you can not download the drive in USB as a package or software , the only way to connect your pc with internet and update the drivers. for internet connection i already describe how to connect internet if your ethernet (LAN) not working , use mobile/datacard for 1 time net connection and update drivers again.

Comment: I wouldnt be too sure about that, I have the .tar file for the driver, I just cant seem to figure out of to install it through the terminal

Comment: .tar file will not work as installing driver , if possible you try to download latest .deb package driver that you can install through terminal and it will work.     
   sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb ( for installing)
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure packagename  ( for reconfigure )
   sudo dpkg -r packagename ( for remove package )